# Bootstrap collapse active

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button class `collapse` with Bootstrap 4.

```
<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body" aria-expanded="true">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

My button with a hidden `div`. On click, it opens. What I want to do is to initialize the div as opened, and then, when I press the button, to be hidden. ( The inverse process.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `in show` class to `collapse` div.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<p>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Button with data-target
  </button>
</p>
<div class="collapse in show" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-body" aria-expanded="true">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap modals or bootstrap dropdowns are good to use

Answer (score 0):

You could add class `show` like this

```
<div class="collapse show" id="collapseExample">
```

Answer (score 0):

add `in` class to `collapse` class div to be `opened` as default

`<div class="collapse in" id="collapseExample">`

`in` is to show the div. whenever you want the div to opened, just add `in` class